# Pulling data from ratemyprofessor.com

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

**Background information:** I'm looking to pull data from ratemyprofessor.com - I have limited programming experience so I decided to see if something was pre-built to accomplish this task.

I came across this here: https://classic.scraperwiki.com/scrapers/ratemyprofessors/

Which is exactly what I'm looking for. ScraperWiki closed down but has it setup to transfer everything to Morph.io - Which I did here: https://morph.io/reddyfire/ratemyprofessors

**My problem:** It doesn't work. It should be outputting a database that gives me information I've identified as needing. I'm assuming it has something to do with the URL it's pulling from:

```
response = scraperwiki.scrape("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=%s&pageNo=%s" % (sid,str(i)))
```

But I have no idea if that's right. I'm feeling pretty defeated by this but I want to keep going for a solution.

What I need: I'm looking to get the **Name, Department,Total Ratings,Overall Quality, Easiness, and Hotness rating for each instructor at the colleges. Here's some sample output in the desired format:

```
 {"953":("Stanford",32),"799":("Rice",17),"780":("Princeton",16)}
```

Comment: What data do you want exactly? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The more specific you are, the better we can help you isolate your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my post to be more specific as well as post it here. I'm looking to get the following information from each teacher at each school searched: ["Name","Department","Total Ratings","Overall Quality","Easiness","Hot"]

Comment: Okay, that's the first bit. You're using a premade solution. What part of it doesn't work for you?

Comment: When I run the script on https://morph.io/reddyfire/ratemyprofessors it's not spitting out the data I'm looking for. I've seen this code worked in the past but it was over a year ago which makes me wonder if the URL I'm looking at is wrong (mentioned in my post above)?

Comment: It could be that they changed the layout of the website as well. I see that you're new here and I don't want to be harsh, but without a specific explanation of what you tried, what happened, and what you'd like to happen its hard for me (or anyone else) to answer your question.

Comment: Absolutely understandable. I appreciate you responding. I don't really have any other info to provide as I haven't been able to provide much. I just have a template and what I need. It could be I should just leave this project alone until I learn more. - Also saying that is not being harsh. :)

Comment: I think the URL is fine, but consider using a different library (forewarning--you'll have to write some code), a good tutorial is [this one](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/). Also consider reading up on some HTML if you're unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested to do a simplified scraper for you. Do note that it isnt pythonic (ie not beautiful or fast), but as a starting point it works.

```
__author__ = 'Victor'
import urllib
import re
url = 'http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=306975'

def crawlURL(addedURL):
    url = addedURL
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

    teacherData = re.findall(r'\">(.*?)</',html)

    output = ''
    addStuff = 0
    for x in xrange(len(teacherData)):
        if teacherData[x] == 'Submit a Correction':
            output = 'professor: '
            for y in xrange(4):
                output += teacherData[x-8+y] + ' '
            addStuff = 1
        elif teacherData[x] == 'Helpfulness' and addStuff == 1:
            output += ': Overall quality: '+ str(teacherData[x-2]) + ': Average grade: ' + str(teacherData[x-1]) + ': Helpfulness: ' + teacherData[x+1]
        elif teacherData[x] == 'Easiness' and addStuff == 1:
            output += ': Easiness: ' + str(teacherData[x+1])
            addStuff = 0
            break
    print output
crawlURL(url)
```

It renders this output:

> Dr.   Kimora John Jay College : Overall quality: 5.0: Average grade:
>   A: Helpfulness: 5.0 : Easiness: 4.6

There is plenty of room for improvement, but this is as close to pseudcode i could get.

In this example it is a function that prints the output, if you want to add it to a list just add a "return output" in the end and call the function with "listName.append(crawlURL(url))"

This is for Python 2.7

And yes, it doesnt get the exact data you requested. It just opens the door for you ;)

EDIT:
Here is an example on how to loop the requests

```
def crawlURL(addesURL):
    ...
    return output

baseURL = 'http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=306'
for x in xrange(50):
    url = baseURL + str(x+110)
    if crawlURL(url) != '': print crawlURL(url)
```

If you are iterating through all of their data you should consider to add delays every now and then so you dont accidentally DDoS them.